# Get latest tag commit from bitbucket api 2.0

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I am trying to create a utility tool for which I need to get the latest tag committed to a specific repo.
I have tried so far:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<team>/<reposlug>/refs/tags \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic encodedpasswd' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Host: api.bitbucket.org'
```

What I get in return is paginated response, like this:

```
{
    "pagelen": 10,
    "values": [
        {
            "name": "release-1.2",
            "links": {
            },
            "tagger": {
            
            },
            "date": "2019-11-15T11:53:56+00:00",
            "message": "[maven-release-plugin]copy for tag release-1.2\n",
            "type": "tag",
            "target": {
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "release-1.3",
            "links": {
            },
            "tagger": {
            },
            "date": "2019-11-20T07:53:51+00:00",
            "message": "[maven-release-plugin]copy for tag release-1.3\n",
            "type": "tag",
            "target": {
            }
        }
    ],
    "page": 1
}
```

Now as per the documentation I have referred through [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/refs/tags), `tags` are specially ordered when returned, but I am confused as to why the value `release-1.3` is not first in the response. I think I am missing something. Or if this is the expected order, how can I achieve the tags sorted on `date` attribute, to get the latest tag.

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to solve this by using `sort` on attribute `target.date`.

```
   curl -X GET \
  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<team>/<reposlug>/refs/tags?sort=target.date \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic encodedpasswd' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Host: api.bitbucket.org'
```

Comment: Not sure why your answer doesn't have probably the most essential part: sorting in a descending fashion: sort=-target.date

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @Dota2 is nearly correct but the matter of fact is its descending sorted and never give latest commit sorted on top this easily can be done by adding -  to query string like below

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/purevpn/dialerxn/refs/tags?sort=-target.date
```

In json adding - will do assending sort `sort=-target.date`